# Is it possible to use backburner on the student edition of 3ds max?

Tags: 3ds-max

I've got a couple of good quad core machines, am using the student edition of 3ds max, and I'd like to be able to farm the rendering out to both machines, if possible. Anyone know if the student edition will allow this? After Googling around for a while and digging into the support docs at the autodesk site, I'm still not sure on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine with the university editions of 3ds max 6, but that was quite a few years ago.

I would expect the student version would work in the same way, with only licencing differences, and possibly file format import/export limitations.

Comment: Looks like this is correct, I went home yesterday and got it all setup, it appears the render engine never checks the license.  I'll know for sure in 30 days, but so far, so good.  Gotta love building a DIY rendering farm in your apartment.  @paradroid Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Yes (as of 2014).  Due to university network annoyances (security and whatnot) it may be difficult to have the machines talk to each other, though.